# How to copy a range of a single row by only selecting a single cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering what's the script for copying a range (consisting of a single row and a few columns) by only selecting a single cell as the active cell.

For example if my current active cell is A1 or anywhere in Row 1, and I run the script, it would copy A1:F1. If my current active cell is A2 or anywhere in Row 2, it would copy A2:F2.

So far I'm using the getActiveRange line, but I find that this would take time to select A1:F1 then run the script. I find this especially true if there is a lot of items that needed to be copied to different tabs.

The script I am currently using is as below:

```
function fromRDM1() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheetByName('TemplateTarget');

 sheet.copyTo(source).setName('TargetSheet1');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");

  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Line1");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("TargetSheet1");

  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A4");

  source_range.copyTo(target_range);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TargetSheet1'))

}
```

This is off-topic but if anyone knows how I can insert a hyperlink into column G of my selected row (Example, if my current active cell is on A1 or anywhere in Row 1, hyperlink will be pasted on G1, if my current active cell is on A2 or anywhere in Row 2, hyperlink will be pasted on G2), please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to copy the column "A" to "F" of the selected row of the source sheet to the range of "A4" of the destination sheet.

  - For example, when the cell of "B1" of the source sheet is selected, you want to copy "A1:F1" to the range of "A4" of the destination sheet.
  - When the cell of "B1" of the source sheet is selected, you want to put a hyperlink to the cell "G1" of the source sheet.
- From your script, I thought that `var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` and `var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");` are the same Spreadsheet, because if these are the different, an error occurs at `source_range.copyTo(target_range);`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A4");
```

To:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/"; // Added

var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
source_range = source_sheet.getRange(source_range.getRow(), 1, 1, 6); // Added
source_sheet.getRange("G" + source_range.getRow()).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + url + '","sample")') // Added
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A4");
```

- Please set the URL for the hyperlink to the variable of `url`.
- In order to copy the column "A" to "F", the selected row is retrieved by `getRow()`, and the range of column "A" to "F"  of the source sheet is created by `getRange()`.
- In order to put the hyperlink to the column "G", the selected row is retrieved by `getRow()`, and the range of column "G" of the source sheet is created by `getRange()`. Then, the hyperlink is put using `setFormula()`.

#### References:

- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Answer for additional request:

At the reply comment, [the following request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723769/how-to-copy-a-range-of-a-single-row-by-only-selecting-a-single-cell/58724093?noredirect=1#comment103740249_58724093) was added.

> Is there a way to get the Sheet ID for the new sheet using AS then have it pasted into the setFormula url?

For above additional request, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From

```
sheet.copyTo(source).setName('TargetSheet1');
```

To:

```
var newSheet = sheet.copyTo(source).setName('TargetSheet1');
```

and

From:

```
var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A4");
```

To:

```
var url = source.getUrl() + "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId(); // Added

var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
source_range = source_sheet.getRange(source_range.getRow(), 1, 1, 6); // Added
source_sheet.getRange("G" + source_range.getRow()).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + url + '","sample")') // Added
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A4");
```

- You can also use `var url = "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId();` instead of `var url = source.getUrl() + "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId();`.

Comment: This hit the nail at the right spot. Exactly what I needed and how I wanted it to function. Just another quick off-topic question. Is there a way to get the Sheet ID for the new sheet using AS then have it pasted into the setFormula url?

Comment: @Jme Sekaiichi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Jme Sekaiichi About your additional request, I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Checked the modified script, and yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you, again. You saved me a lot of time preparing this workbook.

Comment: @Jme Sekaiichi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. You can also use `var url = "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId();` instead of `var url = source.getUrl() + "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId();`. This might be more simple.